# Taking columns from a dataframe based on row values of another dataframe in Python?

Tags: python

I am working with 2 dataframes, I am trying to create multiple dfs from `df1` based on row values of `df2`. I am unable to find any documentation around how to get this done.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': 'foo bar bro bir fin car zoo loo'.split(),
    'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
    'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2
})
print(df1)


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': 'foo bar bro bir'.split(),
    'col2': 'B B C B '.split(),
    'col3': 'D C D D '.split()
})
print(df2)
```

How do I create a dataframe called `'foo'` which takes only columns `B` and `D` in `df1` (which are inputs from `df2`). 
Same for another dataframe `'bar'`, `'bro'` & `'bir'`. So an example of the output of `df_foo` & `df_bar` will be

```
df_foo = pd.DataFrame({'B': 'one', 'D': 0})

df_bar = pd.DataFrame({'B': 'one', 'C': 1})
```

I could not find any documentation on how can this be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for (label based) indexing? An example:

```
df1_ = df1.set_index('A')              # use column A to "rename" rows.
print(df1_.loc[('foo',), ('B', 'D')])  # use `.loc` to access values via their label coordinates.
# 
#        B  D
# A          
# foo  one  0
```

So, to build a new dataframe by taking `df2`'s rows as input to be used within `df1`, you can do

```
df_all = pd.concat((
    df1_.loc[(row.col1,), (row.col2, row.col3)]
    for _, row in df2.iterrows()
))
print(df_all)
#         B    C    D
# A                   
# foo    one  NaN  0.0
# bar    one  1.0  NaN
# bro    NaN  2.0  4.0
# bir  three  NaN  6.0
```

and finally, an example with `'bar'` (replace `'bar'` by `'foo'` or whatever)

```
df_bar = df_all.loc['bar'].dropna()
print(df_bar)            
# B    one
# C      1
# Name: bar, dtype: object

# or, to keep playing with dataframes
print( df_all.loc[('bar',), :].dropna(axis=1) )
#        B    C
# A            
# bar  one  1.0
```

---

If you have more than 3 columns, lets say 70-80 columns in `df1`, something you can do is

```
idx     = 'col1'
cols    = [c for c in df2.columns.tolist() if c != idx]
df_agno = pd.concat((
    df1_.loc[
        (row[idx],), row[cols]
    ] for _, row in df2.iterrows()
))
print(df_agno)
#          B    C    D
# A                   
# foo    one  NaN  0.0
# bar    one  1.0  NaN
# bro    NaN  2.0  4.0
# bir  three  NaN  6.0

print( df_agno.loc[('bar',), :].dropna(axis=1) )             
#        B    C
# A            
# bar  one  1.0
```

Comment: what if i have more than 3 columns, lets say 70-80 columns in df1, how would this work without mentioning all column names?

Comment: hi keepAlive, the output that you previously shared was correct to my purpose, the new one is not. both the outputs are not the same

Comment: I am facing issue as ([Lac,]) not in index when df2 has say 'col1': 'foo bar bro bir lac'.split(). In this case is it possible to still get the desired output without the error?